# Add item dependently

Tags: javascript

I am have a cart with items where each item, when clicked, will update the item count and price.

```
      return {
        itemCount: 0,
        price: 0,
        itemAdd: function () {
          this.itemCount += 1;
          if (this.itemCount <= 5) {
            this.price = 500 + (110 * this.itemCount)
          } else if (this.itemCount > 5, this.itemCount <= 10) {
            this.price = 1000 + (105 * this.itemCount)
          } else if (this.itemCount > 10) {
            this.price = 1500 + (90 * this.itemCount)
          }
          document.getElementById("itemPrice").innerText = this.price;
          document.getElementById("itemCount").innerText = this.itemCount;
        },
      }
    }
```

When I click on one item twice, the price and itemCount is updated accordingly. However, when I click on a new item, the itemCount and price "reset" and start from zero. When I go back and click on the first item again, it continues counting from 2. What am I not getting right here?

Comment: It's got something to do with the `this` binding. Could you include where you're calling the function?

Comment: can you provide a minimum reproducible code example

Comment: Make `itemCount` and `price` global by setting them out of the Object and function (Above the function)

Comment: @Julius now I get `itemCount` of NaN and `price` of undefined

Comment: Please show your entire code

Comment: @Julius https://codepen.io/reonLOW/pen/PozgrGQ?editors=1010, I did some editing and this is what I manage to get.

Comment: After making `itemCount` and `price` global, stop referring to them using `this`

Comment: @Julius in what case do I refer or not refer using `this`?

Comment: Refer with `this` within the method or Object where the variable was constructed. Not outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now update to this..

```
 let price = 0;
 let itemCount = 0;
 const getData = () => {
 return {
  items: [],
  itemAdd: function() {
    itemCount += 1;
    if (itemCount <= 5) {
      price = 500 + 110 * itemCount;
    } else if ((itemCount > 5, itemCount <= 10)) {
      price = 1000 + 105 * itemCount;
    } else if (itemCount > 10) {
      price = 1500 + 90 * itemCount;
    }
    document.getElementById("itemPrice").innerHTML = price;
    document.getElementById("itemCount").innerHTML = itemCount;
  }
};
};
```